# Weird Mask R-CNN prediction results from CT images

Tags: deep-learning, prediction, x-ray, mask-rcnn

I have recently initiated the training of Mask R-CNN for concrete particle detection and segmentation, specifically targeting coarse aggregates, voids, and cracks in X-ray CT grayscale scans. To build the model, I have relied on the architecture provided in this GitHub repository (https://github.com/Kamlesh364/Mask-RCNN-TF2.7.0-keras2.7.0).

Currently, I'm in the initial stages of model development, testing it on a limited dataset with only one epoch to assess instance prediction accuracy.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyVQT.png) However, I've encountered an issue with the output images and predictions, which are illustrated in the images below. I also attempted to predict objects using the COCO class, but I consistently observe the same box pattern.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide insights into the nature of this problem and its potential connections to other issues.

I have attempted to modify the configuration file to address this issue. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdUCu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UIas.jpg)But I initially used the provided repository with a tested dataset. However, I encountered the problem I described earlier. Any guidance or insights on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.